# Semigroups containing an ideal with a local identity

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, ideals

I'm looking for some classes of semigroups containing a (proper) ideal with a local identity (i.e., ideal submonoid). Can somebody give some examples or/and theorems  for the followings cases:

(a) Non-commutative and commutative semigroups with an ideal submonoid that is not an ideal subgroup

(b) Semigroups containing a left (resp. right) ideal submonoid that is not two-sided ideal

(c) Semigroups containing a unique ideal submonoid  that is not an ideal subgroup.

**Note.** Every semigroup containing an ideal subgroup is called a homogroup. Also, a homogroup is a grouplike if and only if the set of its central idempotents is a singleton (see [this](http://bims.iranjournals.ir/pdf_305_daa595cb8449dd1f6b4a0cb354aefa32.html) , [this](http://as.yazd.ac.ir/article_741_141.html) and [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm52/fm5216.pdf)).

Comment: You mean an ideal which is a monoid when viewed as a subsemigroup? This is not hard to construct. Take a homomorphism  $f:S\to M$ where S is a semigroup and M is a monoid. You then take $S\cup M$ where you use f to multiply elements of M by S.

Comment: You can also use inflation. Take a monoid M and let $X$ be any set. Consider a map $f\colon X\to M$. Now your semigroup of $X\cup M$ where for any product involving elements of x you first apply f.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your useful comments.

Comment: Could you please give some certain examples or introduce some references